# Express cookieSession doesn't populate req.session

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am using `cookieSession` to attempt to populate the `req.session` object with a cookie for non-authenticated users. But, after passing `cookieSession` a key, the `req.session` object is never populated.

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cookieSession({keys: ['key1', 'key2']}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session); // Empty object
    console.log(req.cookies);
    next();
});
```

This is using `express 4`. How else can I populate the `req.session` object, or what am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untill you assign anything to session object you will get empty object {}.

For example, once you user logged in , you can set userId or emailId to session object.

```
req.session.userId = "1";
```

Once you set value to session , you can read it using req.session

Comment: If you would like to track the user, would it be wise to assign the cookie to the req.session manually? Or is it customary to just leave it in the cookie.session object? It seems intuitively like it would make sense to keep the cookie in the session object.

Comment: Cookie parser encrypt the session object in writes in the cookie. If you check cookie, then you can find express:sess key which is encrypted key for your session object. So Internally session uses the same cookie to achieve this